# Is exporting bookmarks possible in PhpStorm?

Tags: phpstorm

I would like to use same set of bookmarks in two computers. Is it possible?

Comment: Bookmarks? They are per-project .. so should be stored in `.idea` subfolder (`workspace.xml` file most likely); which means -- if you copy whole project onto another computer it should be available there as well (it's the case here).

Comment: thanks, You can move it as an answer. I will approve it.

Comment: You can also give https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-98138 a vote or submit your own request specifically requesting Bookmarks import/export functionality.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bookmarks are per-project entities ... so they are stored together with other project specific settings in `.idea` subfolder (`workspace.xml` file in particular).

This means -- if you copy whole project folder across to another computer then all bookmarks should be preserved (it's the case here).